# Function extending a Lipschitz function

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces, holder-spaces

Let $X$ be a metric space with a metric $d$, let $E\subset X$. 
We have a function $f:E \rightarrow \mathbb R$ satisfying for some $M>0$:
$$
|f(x)-f(y)|\leq M d(x,y) \quad \text{for } x,y \in E.
$$

I wish to show that a function 
$$
F(x)=\sup_{y \in E} [f(y)-M d(x,y)] 
$$
for  $x \in X$, is finite (that is $F: X \rightarrow \mathbb R$).

Comment: From the Lipschitz condition, you have $f(y)-f(x)\leq M d(x,y)$, so that $f(y)-Md(x,y)\leq f(x)$. Doesn't this solve it?

Comment: From this condition follows that $F$ is finite but on $E$.

Comment: If $x\notin E$, let $z\in E$ be arbitrary, then $f(y)-Md(x,y)=f(y)-Md(z,y)+M(d(z,y)-d(x,y))$, but from the triangle inequality $d(z,y)-d(x,y)\leq d(z,x)$ so hat $f(y)-Md(x,y)\leq f(z)+Md(z,x)$.

Comment: Related: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirszbraun_theorem

Comment: @user38773: I think that's an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x\in E$, then $f(y)-f(x)\leq Md(x,y)$ so that $f(y)-Md(x,y)\leq f(x)$ and hence $F(x)\leq f(x)$.

If $x\notin E$, let $z\in E$ be arbitrary, then $f(y)-Md(x,y)=f(y)-Md(z,y)+M(d(z,y)-d(x,y))$, but from the triangle inequality $d(z,y)-d(x,y)\leq d(z,x)$ so that $f(y)-Md(x,y)\leq f(z)+Md(z,x)$ and hence $F(x)\leq f(z)+Md(z,x)$.